# SOLR synonym not working for certain keyword

Tags: solr

I have solr synonym file with this data

> aaa => bra
>
> fff => bras

Searching "aaa" shows some result. (same result as bra)

Searching "bra" shows some result

Searching "bras" shows some result

Searching "fff" doesn't show any result

What could be possibly an issue here?

**Update: This is the schema**

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">

      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
       <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the schema definition for the field types used? It could be a problem of the order in which you do your transformations, for instance if you stem "bras" to "bra" before applying the synonyms, it would give different results.

Comment: I have added schema details. I just do StandardTokenizerFactory before checking synonym.

Comment: Do you have an example document that doesn't match?

Comment: Can you run the query and include the `debugQuery=true` parameter? This should return the actual parsed query and should be able to tell us if something is wrong

Comment: I would suggest logging into the UI and use the analysis function to determine how transformations are applied and why there is not hit as you described it.